# Installed Laravel in subfolder but home page shows Index of

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I know there are lots of similar posts but after 3 hours of research I still can't find a solution. Hope someone can help.

Technologies used:

- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Laravel 5.4
- PHP 7.0

/etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin stanley@example.com
        Servername example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                #AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/html/example.com/parcgilley/public">
                Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    .......
```

So the document root sits at /var/www/html/example.com, and my laravel site resides in /var/www/html/example.com/parcgilley. I tried to configure 000-default.conf to point my site to /var/www/html/example.com/parcgilley/public, but when I go to example.com/parcgilley, it shows "Index of /parcgilley". And when I navigates to http://www.example.com/parcgilley/public/, Chrome shows "This page isn’t working".

This is my public/.htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This is not the original content. I followed the instructions from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#pretty-urls), so I replaced the origin with the above code.

Also, I have set the permissions for the /parcgilley project root folder and the storage folder, but to no avail.

I don't know if I need to create .htaccess file to point to the /public folder. But I don't know much about apache configuration.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Edited:

Also I used SSH and Git to push the website from my local machine to the server, with the bare repo siting at /var/repo/site.git. I don't know if that relates to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable the directory listing via .htaccess?

```
Options -Indexes
```

Here is more info:
https://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml